# Searching attributes of an XML's element tree with xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I'm going to use the example from the Python's ElementTree docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Is there a way to search the attributes and return the element for which the attribute matches? In example above, I would like to search for the element whose attribute name is Singapore. The `findall()` function only searches by tag name, i.e. "country", "rank", etc. I know I could cycle through all country tags and see if their name attribute matches Singapore but I'm wondering if there is a faster method using a built-in function that I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example) expressions (like regular expressions, but for XML)

similar to the example above:

```
# Nodes with name='Singapore' that have a 'year' child
root.findall(".//year/..[@name='Singapore']")
```

Comment: Ohh, totally missed that. Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.